# Test if a data distribution follows a Gaussian distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, gaussian

I have some data points and their mean point. I need to find whether those data points (with that mean) follows a Gaussian distribution. Is there a function in MATLAB which can do that kind of a test? Or do I need to write a test of my own?

I tried looking at different statistical functions provided by MATLAB. I am very new to MATLAB so I might have overlooked the right function.

cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hypothesis-tests-1.html) on all [available hypothesis tests](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/available-hypothesis-tests.html).

From those, for your purpose you can use:

- [Chi-square goodness-of-fit test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html)
- [Lilliefors test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html)
- [z-test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ztest.html)
- [t-test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html)
- [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html)

... among others

You can also use some visual tests like:

- [hist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html)
- [normplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normplot.html)
- [cdfplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html)

Comment: I just don't like that these are all from the Mathwork$ $tatistic$ toolbox; one could easily hack together the e.g. Jarque-Bera without it, but for the rest, you have to import some files from `octave`. The other problem with a firehose of statistical tests is there is no indication of the relative power of each of them (true, it depends on the alternative hypothesis).

Comment: yeah, wikipedia links would be nicer. they are more to the point usually and quicker to read.

Answer (score 6):

I like Spiegelhalter's test (D. J. Spiegelhalter, 'Diagnostic tests of distributional shape,' Biometrika, 1983):

```
function pval = spiegel_test(x)
% compute pvalue under null of x normally distributed;
% x should be a vector;
xm = mean(x);
xs = std(x);
xz = (x - xm) ./ xs;
xz2 = xz.^2;
N = sum(xz2 .* log(xz2));
n = numel(x);
ts = (N - 0.73 * n) / (0.8969 * sqrt(n)); %under the null, ts ~ N(0,1)
pval = 1 - abs(erf(ts / sqrt(2)));    %2-sided test.
```

whenever hacking statistical tests, alway test them under the null! here's a simple example:

```
pvals = nan(10000,1);
for j=1:numel(pvals);
pvals(j) = spiegel_test(randn(300,1));
end
nnz(pvals < 0.05) ./ numel(pvals)
```

I get the results:

```
ans =    
   0.0505
```

Similarly

```
nnz(pvals > 0.95) ./ numel(pvals)
```

I get

```
ans = 
   0.0475
```

Answer (score 5):

For testing in general, look up the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test, also in the Stats Toolbox, as [kstest](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/kstest.html) and the two-sample version: [kstest2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/kstest2.html) . You feed it your empirical data, (and the data from a possible function, like the gaussian, etc...) then it tests the likelihood that your sample was pulled from the normal distribution (or the one you supplied for the two-sample version)... The nicety is that it'll work for any possible distributions...